# How to perform a simple multiple selection in a table ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Here is what my view looks like:

```
@model Affiliate


<div class="box paint color_16">
<div class="title">
    <h4><i class="icon-tasks"></i><span>@Model.CompanyName's Commissions</span> </h4>
</div>
<div class="content top ">
    <div class="subtitle">
        @Html.ActionLink("Void", "DeleteInvoice", new { commList = "??", affId = Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn" })
        @Html.ActionLink("Create Invoice", "CreateInvoice", new { commList = "??", affId = Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn" })
        @Html.ActionLink("Pay", "PayInvoice", new { commList = "??", affId = Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn" })
    </div>

    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <tr>
            <h3>Commissions</h3>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Amount</td>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Commissions)
        {
            <tr>
                @if (item.Status == ViewBag.PaymentStatus || ViewBag.PaymentStatus == "All")
                {
                    <td>@Html.CheckBox("commId", new { value = item.Id })</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.PayoutAmount)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Status)</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

What I want to be able to do is when I hit an actionlink on the top, grab all the items from the table that are checked, and pass that list of id's to the controller logic. I am assuming a viewmodel may be the solution, something like this:

```
 public Affiliate affilite { get; set; }
 public List<int> selectedItems { get; set; }
 etc.
```

But how to I get the selected Items into that VM selectedItems container?

Comment: Why are you mentioning View Models and still using ViewBag in your view? Those 2 things are contradictory and should never be used together. The correct approach is of course to use a view model and get rid of ViewBag. So I would start by defining a real view model for this view. There should be at least a dozen of similar answers on this site in which I have illustrated the usage of view models and editor templates.

Comment: This isn't the finalized code, and if you read the question it is not about his to use a viewmodel. The question is how I tie a viewmodel property to whatever the user selects. Helpful responses are welcome, snark and condescending questions about methods used in mocked up example code belongs in another forum.

Comment: But where is your view model? All I can see is some `Affiliate` domain model that you have put as a property in something that you call *view model*. But that's not how view models work. They should not be referencing your domain models. View models should be defined to reflect the requirements of your views.

Comment: I don't have a viewmodel written right now. It was an off the top of my head idea that may lead to a solution. Not something I have thought out and written yet. All I know is that I have a table strongly types against x, how can I get a list of x.id based off of what the user checked off. Even if it is a comma deliminated string, don't care, just need those int's return to my controller so I can do work with them.  Architecture-wise, there may be a better way, but I am looking for something I can implement off of this domain model to get the list I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off your comments, you don't seem to be looking for the most "correct" answer, but rather just a quick and dirty "how would I do this" answer. If you just want to pass the list, you could setup your controller action like this:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(int[] id)
{
    ...
}
```

Or, you seem to indicate it is strongly typed to a view model with a property that contains a List (I would shorten the name of the property, you'll see why in a second).

In javascript, the easiest thing to do would be to use jQuery to bind a click event on your hyperlink that gets the list of items that are checked and appends that to the query string.

```
$("#myLink").click(function()
{
    var url = "site.com/action?";
    var ids = $(".table").find("input:checked");

    ids.each(function()
    {
        url += "id=" + $(this).val() + "&"
    });

    window.location = url;
});
```

Basically, you want to create one long query string with the action parameter's name repeated over and over, which identifies an array. It looks something like this (id is for int[] id in MyAction):

```
id=15&id=20&id=25&id=30&....
```

And then once the query string is built, redirect the user to that url. MVC should then be able to bind that to an array and you're all set.

That's basically the idea, anyway; the syntax and the javascript I wrote could be way off so don't copy my code and expect it to work as is - I wrote that off the top of my head. If your action is bound to a viewmodel, then you need to set the parameter in the query string to the name of the property of your model:

```
selectedids=1&selectedids=2&selectedids=3...
```

Or, if the array is a property of an object, which is a property of the model...

```
model.selectedids=1&model.selectedids=2&model.selectedids=3...
```

You'll just need to play around with it some.

Answer (score 0):

Use html checks inside form tag ( you could use helpers too) and post the model to a post action.
MVC will serialize the model automatically

Comment: This isn't a form right now, I an looking for a solutin to pass the list of checked items to a separate actionlink. So in the url params I guess

Comment: You could serialize all checks (or a form with checks) in a jQuery post for each action