# Create a link dynamically based on selected items in a table for ASP MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to perform a simple multiple selection in a table ASP.NET MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869533/how-to-perform-a-simple-multiple-selection-in-a-table-asp-net-mvc4)

I have a table of items. Each row is selectable through a checkbox in the row. I have a "Copy" button that allows the user to copy the selected rows and create new entities from them.

To handle this scenario, I have an action on my controller that accepts a list of entity IDs. How do I dynamically create a link to my controller with a parameter list containing the selected item IDs?

I have attempted to use Javascript to identify the selected rows, but I am unsure how to construct the parameter list for the link.

Comment: Take a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13870499/1087945)

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Can you mark it as a duplicate and point it to your answer?